# DB Corruption SQL Server 2008 R2, sharepoint db after upgrade from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sql-server

I am unsure of which fix to use, would repair rebuild work in this case? Or am I looking at something more serious than that? Could I get away with rebuilding the indexes?

Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 34, index ID 4, partition ID 1125899909070848, alloc unit ID 1125899909070848 (type In-row data): Page (1:122) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 34, index ID 4, partition ID 1125899909070848, alloc unit ID 1125899909070848 (type In-row data), page (1:122). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -4.
Msg 8980, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 34, index ID 4, partition ID 1125899909070848, alloc unit ID 1125899909070848 (type In-row data). Index node page (1:704), slot 0 refers to child page (1:122) and previous child (0:0), but they were not encountered.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 34, index ID 4, partition ID 1125899909070848, alloc unit ID 1125899909070848 (type In-row data). Page (3:2079) is missing a reference from previous page (1:122). Possible chain linkage problem.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 4 consistency errors in table 'sys.sysschobjs' (object ID 34).
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057594043826176 (type LOB data): Page (1:15576063) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057594043826176 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:15576063), slot 0, text ID 1169396858880 is referenced by page (1:15489188), slot 0, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057594043826176 (type LOB data): Page (1:16367391) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057594043826176 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:16367391), slot 0, text ID 579107225600 is referenced by page (1:16365934), slot 0, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057594043826176 (type LOB data): Page (1:17576351) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057594043826176 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:17576351), slot 0, text ID 564993523712 is referenced by page (1:17575869), slot 0, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057594043826176 (type LOB data): Page (1:24942485) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057594043826176 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24942485), slot 0, text ID 988802777088 is referenced by page (1:24865665), slot 0, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057594043826176 (type LOB data): Page (3:607920) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057594043826176 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (3:607920), slot 0, text ID 2035679232 is referenced by page (3:607848), slot 0, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057610557259776 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 2035679232 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:29664720:54)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057610557259776 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 564993523712 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:29878016:55)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057610557259776 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 988802777088 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:3470791:60)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057610557259776 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 2035679232 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:3474835:95)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057610557259776 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 2035679232 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:3477426:31)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057610557259776 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 1169396858880 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:3477446:19)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057610557259776 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 579107225600 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:3642889:2)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 277576027, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610147856384, alloc unit ID 72057610557259776 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 2035679232 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:3721119:23)
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 18 consistency errors in table 'AllDocStreams' (object ID 277576027).
Msg 8964, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057594046578688 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:18265600), slot 4, text ID 448266240 is not referenced.
Msg 8964, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057594046578688 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:18266307), slot 8, text ID 2116222976 is not referenced.
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:273050:8)
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Page (1:290399) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data), page (1:290399). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -4.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data), page (1:290399). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -4.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data). Page (1:290399) was not seen in the scan although its parent (3:3606839) and previous (3:3742947) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:291235:8)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:294056:6)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:299200:2)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:311477:3)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 2116222976 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:37332:2)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:40111:1)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:49517:2)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 2116222976 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:53304:7)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:53316:6)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 2116222976 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:59537:4)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:66594:6)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:67832:9)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:86641:6)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:3477728:0)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 448266240 owned by data record identified by RID = (3:3699831:0)
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1365579903, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610123214848, alloc unit ID 72057610533339136 (type In-row data). Page (3:3742948) is missing a reference from previous page (1:290399). Possible chain linkage problem.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 23 consistency errors in table 'AllUserData' (object ID 1365579903).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 45 consistency errors in database 'dbname'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (dbname).

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and give it a shot.  Your other (and much less attractive) option is repair_allow_data_loss which should be a method of last resort.  If you have the option of rolling back your upgrade of Sharepoint (you did do it against a copy of the original db, I hope), I'd do that and investigate why these errors came up.  Best of luck.